# Makefile arduino uno "make: *** No rule to make target `sketch.hex', needed by `all'."

Tags: makefile, arduino

I am trying to write a makefile to compile my sample arduino program in CLI. I am using the default base makefile [here](http://pastebin.com/z0HneVNX), and my makefile which extends it looks like this.

```
ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino
BOARD_TAG = uno
ARDUINO_PORT = /dev/ttyACM0
ARDUINO_LIBS = 
include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
```

This is what happends when I run make.

```
$ make
cat build-uno/sketch.d > build-uno/depends.mk
make: *** No rule to make target `sketch.hex', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

I also tried this kind of thing in the makefile (I saw it online somewhere while googling)

```
$(TARGET_HEX): bin/$(TARGET)
```

But that results in this

```
make: *** No rule to make target `bin/My', needed by `build-uno/My'.  Stop.
```

**Edit**
Got it working with sublime text, and thats good enough for me. I just hate the default IDE.

Comment: Could you post the default makefile if it's small, or give a link to it if it's big?

Comment: Can't help with the first question as we are not familiar with "arduino" and have no idea what's in its "default base makefile".  I will say that for the second question, I _suspect_ that you are trying to use a pathname containing whitespace (that the variable `TARGET` has a value like `My File` or whatever).  Make does not support, for all practical purposes, whitespace in pathnames so you'll have to rename those.

Comment: ok, added the link in. I did make sure that I got rid of all whitespace in the pathname before pasting it that I could see, however, I have a symlink to a windows "my documents" folder on a different partition (using linux for this). When I run pwd I get the symlinked version. Is it possible that the program is seeing the original version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't get what I was originally hoping for, I got a solution which works just as well for me (since I simply didn't want the original IDE). I simply got it working with sublime text with this [plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Arduino-like%20IDE).

For anyone who specifically wants a CLI way to compile, I would suggest using this plugin and then taking a look at the settings files and copy them to your project. The git repo for the project is [here](https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino)

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing your own Makefile from scratch?

I also hate the Arduino IDE and prefer to use ST2 instead, so I'm using a personal fork of Sudar's Arduino Make file here: https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Arduino-Makefile
It is based on the makefile you are using but with major improvements

Here are the instructions I wrote for my project: https://github.com/WeAreLeka/moti/blob/master/USE.md

Feel free to fork and contribute!

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, I changed about 1 line in the default makefile at /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk.
What I am using is actually a whole plugin for sublime text that makes it really easy. Control alt V to compile, or control alt U to compile and upload. You can get the plugin [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Arduino-like%20IDE)

Comment: Yeah that's a great plugin I used to use. When your project gets bigger with many libraries and classes, you might want to go full command line. You also might want to use Sublime Clang to check you C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a small but in `Arduino-Makefile`, it fails in this way if there are any spaces in your arduino sketch file name, or *anywhere* in the path leading to your arduino sketch.

An easy solution is to just ensure there are no spaces in any folder or filename.